# Saving the content of a meta-tag using selenium IDE

Tags: selenium-ide

I would like to save the content of a meta-tag e.g.
`<meta name="description" content="This is test meta description!" />`

I tried this:

```
<td>store</td>
<td>//meta[@name='description']</td>
<td>b</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>echo</td>
<td>${b}</td>
<td></td>
</tr>
```

and my result in Selenium IDE at echo was:

```
[info] Executing: |echo | ${b} | |
[info] echo: //meta[@name='description']
```

But I need to get the content. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

Below is solution for scenario

```
storeAttribute  |  //meta[@name='description']@content  |  variable
echo  | ${variable}
```